# Hide home page and index page name from url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I have a website, say www.example.com (not actual name).
In this website I have

> index.php (first page of website before login) and home.php (first
>   page of website after login)

As my DirectoryIndex index.php(in .htaccess), index.php does not appear in address bar. But when logged in, it shows home.php as a part of link.

I **don't** want to **show "home.php" in url**. I was thinking to use some url rewrite rules in .htaccess, but I'm stuck.

Is there any easy solution for this?

Please let me know if you guys need any other system/server related info, if required.

//Edit
I got this idea from facebook.com.

Comment: The easiest way, imho, is to have the single landing page index.php, which should include public.php or private.php (home.php in your case) depending from logged out/logged in state.

Comment: I saw all the answers, but @Stan ur solution is exactly I wanted for. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way, imho, is to have the single landing page `index.php`, which should include `public.php` or `private.php` (`home.php` in your case) depending from logged out/logged in state.

Answer (score 2):

One way doing such a thing is using some sort of controller in your php script. Check at the beginning of the script to see if logged in and depending on the answer, require the appropriate code. You would not need .htaccess for such a thing!

You could always rename your home.php to something nicer sounding like `/home` using a simple redirect.

```
RewriteRule ^home/?$ home.php [NC,L]
```

That will show the home.php page when browsing to yoursite.com/home. Obviously this will be accessible even if not logged in but as you seem to be implying you do not plan showing the link if not logged in!

Answer (score 0):

Using a webserver redirect, as you mentioned, would only be a workaround.

Your issue is the PHP script itself. It of course does not know your URI setup and *DirectoryIndex* file, and thus uses home.php as an URL target.

So you are left with two options:

- Make the webserver redirect `/home.php` to `/`
- Adjust your PHP script to point to `home.php`
- Adjust your PHP script to check when `home.php` is loaded, if the URI is `/home.php` , and then redirect to `/`

It’s hard to say what the best option is. But your URI setup (directory index) is more likely to change than your php file name. Thus I’d go for the webserver configuration – a [303 redirect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_303) to `/`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on the index.php page

```
<?php require('home.php');?
```

where home.php is the main page for the url (without the qoute of course)